# Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at guacamole-common.min.js

Tags: javascript, guacamole, guacamole-common.js

We are using guacamole-common-js in one of our projects and using guacamole-common.min.js in the script results in a module not found error:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="guacamole-common.min.js"></script>
```

[image: console image]

[image: error in guacamole.min.js]

I am using guacamole-common.js: `1.4.0-a`

At first, I thought this might be related to guacamole-common.js version but I tried downgrading its version but still facing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `module.exports` indicates that the file is a [CommonJS module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html). This is the default module format of Node.js and is not supported by browsers.

Either:

- You have a module designed for Node.js and not web browsers. There might be a browser targetted version available.
- You have a module designed for use with a module bundling tool (such as Webpack or Parcel) and should use one of those to build your browser-side JS application.

Try carefully reading the documentation from wherever you downloaded the JS file from.